# Why does my approve edit no longer count?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

If I approve an edit in the Review section of this site, the post is updated and so my approval worked!

However, if I'm looking at a post and notice there is an edit waiting

[image]

and click on edit and then approve it, I get the message

> This suggestion still needs 1 approve vote from other reviewers. Close
>   this popup (or hit Esc) to continue.

Is this a bug or feature?

Comment: which ones did you approve?

Comment: @Sathya http://superuser.com/questions/529274/microsoft-word-2007 (and it still states edit(1))

Comment: @Sathya Typical, it's just been updated by another user!

Answer (score 5):

Suggested edit approval rules were [revised few months ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151536/133693) and now require a majority of 2 votes to be approved/rejected.

The edit on [How to convert PDF to Microsoft Word 2007-format ?](https://superuser.com/questions/529274/microsoft-word-2007) was approved by you & needed another approval vote [to be vetted & passed through](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/69199), which I have done now & hence is accepted.

The [other suggested edit](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/68940) was already approved by one user and needed a secondary approval vote for it to be accepted, and since yours was the second approval vote, the edit got accepted when you clicked approve.

So yes this is a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Thank you, as always, for taking the time. This is now nice and clear, I thought may be I had been 'down graded' or similar. Thanks

Comment: @DaveRook No downgrades were applied on you, though there are such cases being done - esp at [so], but none here IIRC. You're welcome